# Is there more reliable notion of equivalence of two sets than bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, definition

I know that common sense is to define set $A$ to be equivalent to a set $B$ if and only if there exists a bijection between these two.

Using that definition I can easily state that $\mathbb{N} \equiv \{ 2, 4, 6, \dotsc \} \subset \mathbb{N}$. Hence it can be seen that the bijection-based of equivalence is not that precise and sensitive: I just lost a countable infinity of numbers somewhere and yet it states the two sets are "almost the same".

Are there more precise, more sensitive notions of equivalence?

Comment: Two sets A and B have the [same cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Comparing_sets) if there exists a bijection (a.k.a., one-to-one correspondence) from A to B, that is, a function from A to B that is both injective and surjective. Such sets are said to be equipotent, equipollent, or equinumerous. What do you mean with "a more reliable notion of equivalence"?

Comment: I wouldn't use the expression "Common sense". I would say that it's a natural extension from **finite to infinite** sets.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I mean such a notion that does not prove two sets are equivalent when they differ in an infinite number of elements.

Comment: We do not call them "equivalent": we call them *equinumerous* and this does not mean that they are "equal".

Comment: $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $\{ 4,5,6 \}$ are equinuomerous also in the usual intuitive sense and they are not "equal".

Comment: There is no notion of "equivalence" of sets per se. There *is* the notion of having the size/cardinality which is the notion you are talking about.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA OK, just replace "equivalent" with the "equinumerous". They still differ in the infinite number of elements and they still have proven to be equinumerous. Does a stricter version of "equinumerous" exist?

Comment: Indeed, one characteristic of an infinite set is that it can be put in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang so it comes somewhere from the ZFC axiomatization?

Comment: No, it's a question of **definition** not axioms. And no-one has proposed a theory based on another "equivalence". Just consensus. Deal with it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma so ZFC defines an (countably or uncountably) infite set as one that can be put in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset?

Comment: ZFC does not *define* anything. You define something in the framework of ZFC maybe, but this notion predates ZFC and is due to Cantor himself, the "founding father" of set theory.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't get it. Can you please be a little more clear?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what ZFC is.

Comment: See H.Enderton, [Elements of Set theory](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Elements_of_Set_Theory/DOnkAH-I02sC), page 129, Definition of *equinumerous*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define two sets to be equivalent if their symmetric difference is finite. This does differentiate between $\mathbb{N}$ and $2\mathbb{N}$; however, it does not differentiate between finite sets. If that does not suit you, you could define two sets to be equivalent if they can be put in a bijection *and* their symmetric difference is finite, which gives the same equivalence classes for infinite sets, plus the usual finite sets.

However, I do not think that this definition leads to any interesting results - in a sense, it is almost the same as set equality. Indeed, it seems to me that one of the reasons why the usual definition of cardinality leads to such a fascinating theory is because of how coarse it is, while not being so coarse as to be useless.

Comment: [+1] I like very much the philosophy of the second paragraph. It is exactly the same type of answer one could give to the question in boolean algebra"why $p \implies q$ is the same as $\lnot p \lor q$" (particular case  "why is False implying anything" ?)